# Cant Open Flash Exe File

Tags: flash

so i about 3months ago i had accidently uninstalled my flash(on my windows 8.1 laptop) just to play my old childhood game that was discontinued

so im askin if are there any help i cant get since im desperate to use flash on this exe flash game

if i can post a link here's the exe flash game
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5BC6_SbsgY5HCexeI_GBOTW7WljIJuU/view
its grimoire 3.8+

i cant open it just shows on the system tray and then not popping up on screen

Comment: This is a very generic and very unspecific question (which is also off-scope because it is not a **programming** question). Then, you should perform some research prior to asking, there are answers how to run this game (including Flash Player problem) if you google its name.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback.